# Automapper: Flattening

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I've tried everything to map from Item class to ItemDto class (basically a flattening map) but I keep getting a null for ItemDto.NestedItemName:

```
public class Item
{
    public NestedItem NestedItem{get;set;}
}

public class NestedItem
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}

public class ItemDto
{
    public string NestedItemName{get;set;}
}
```

I would have thought this would work:

```
CreateMap<NestedItem, ItemDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.NestedItemName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

but it returns null. Any ideas?
I'm using AutoMapper 7.0.1 in a .Net Core 2.1 app.

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html

Comment: Please show this in an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't see the content of object you're mapping, nor the code that executes the mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong mapping. More than likely it would be the item being converted to the dto so the map should be created using that

```
CreateMap<Item, ItemDto>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.NestedItemName, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.NestedItem.Name)
    );
```

*From comments*

> There is be no need for the custom mapping, the default naming conventions covers this

Comment: There is no need for custom mapping, the default naming convention covers it.

Comment: Sorry Lucian, I accidentally unaccepted your reply as an answer, and then re-accepted it. If you received any notifications regarding this, please ignore. And thanks for your help!

Comment: I consider this a work-around, not an answer. AutoMapper should be perfectly able to carry out the flattening itself. But we don't see enough code to tell why it doesn't.